remove embossed border from the selected tab
I have a left oriented tabcontrol in a form I'm working on. My goal is to make it so that the indicator of the selected tab is that the tab title becomes underlined but does not change color or anything. In the image below, you can see a border that is placed on the selected tab that's intended to make the tab look raised. I can't figure out how to remove this feature from the tabcontrol. Please advise.

The code below is how I'm orienting the text and controlling the color. I've tried increasing the size of the rectangle for each tab but it appears that the rectangle being drawn is underneath the border so I can't cover it.
`private void FFTSettingsTabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the working area of the TabControl main control
    Rectangle rec = FFTSettingsTabControl.ClientRectangle;
    
    //Create a StringFormat object to set the layout of the label text
    StringFormat StrFormat = new StringFormat();
    StrFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;// Set the text to be centered vertically
    StrFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;// Set the text to be centered horizontally

    // The background fill color of the label, it can also be a picture (e.Graphics.DrawImage)
    SolidBrush backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)20, (byte)20, (byte)20));
    Pen p = new Pen(backColor);
    SolidBrush fontColor;// Label font color
                         //Draw the background of the main control
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColor, rec);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rec);

    //Draw label style
    Font fntTab = e.Font;
    Font fntSel = new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Underline);

    Brush bshBack = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)20, (byte)20, (byte)20));

    for (int i = 0; i < FFTSettingsTabControl.TabPages.Count; i++)
    {
        bool bSelected = (FFTSettingsTabControl.SelectedIndex == i);
        Rectangle recBounds = FFTSettingsTabControl.GetTabRect(i);
        RectangleF tabTextArea = (RectangleF)FFTSettingsTabControl.GetTabRect(i);
        if (bSelected)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bshBack, recBounds);
            fontColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(FFTSettingsTabControl.TabPages[i].Text, fntSel, fontColor, tabTextArea, StrFormat);
        }
        else
        {
            fontColor = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(FFTSettingsTabControl.TabPages[i].Text, fntTab, fontColor, tabTextArea, StrFormat);
        }
    }
}`


When the OwnerDrawFixed draw mode is set, the TabControl raises the DrawItem event whenever it needs to paint a specific TabPage, not all of them. So, the control raises the event for each TabPage control. Drawing them all in this event is wrong. Use this approach to create a custom TabControl and draw everything yourself in the OnPaint method override. See this Q&A for example.

I wasn't aware that the drawItem event was called for all of them individually. I'll amend the code to reflect. However, I saw that thread. and there doesn't seem to be a line dedicated to the border. Am I overlooking it, perhaps?

Which border? Tab button? TabPage client area? TabControl? If you mean the tab button, draw the border in the for..loop. i.e. g.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkRed, r); where r is the button's bounds the GetTabRect(tabIndex) method returns.

In the picture you can see the white partial border surrounding "Devices" on 3 sides. From what I've tried, simply trying to draw in that area doesn't cover those lines. That border gets drawn on top

Yes, that's what you get with OwnerDrawFixed which does not prevent the native control from drawing the other parts including that border. You need to takeover and paint the control yourself to get what you want. See in the referred solution the code in the constructor that sets the styles SetStyle(...);. This is how you tell the native control I got the painting part. Also note you need to override the OnPaint method to draw the control. Forget the DrawItem / OnDrawItem.
